# "Brain dead"ing APC UPSes: likely to be helpful?

Tags: ups

I recently got a SUA750RM1U which developed problems shortly after installation; dropping communications with apcupsd, lighting up the load lights in improbable fashions, beeping continuously for no apparent reason, switching to battery and staying there when the other UPS right next to it is just fine.

APC's response was to "brain dead" it. (And use "Power Chute" instead, but, whatever.)

So: Does this brain deading tend to do anything useful for Smart UPSes? I've never had to deal with this before, and, basically, I'd like to know when, if ever, I can trust the UPS to run production equipment again.

(added: clearly I need to, and will, RMA this particular unit. but I'm still interested to know if this "brain dead"ing ever seems to solve problems, for future reference.)

Comment: Since you do not define "brain dead"ing, it is hard to answer this question. Do you mean relying on Serial instead of network connectivity for shutdown signalling?

Comment: "Brain dead"ing was a specific procedure APC was referring to; as I recall, it consisted of holding the buttons down at the same time after cycling the power, or something.

Comment: I received the same answer from APC with a similar problem a month after purchase - evidently this company is going downhill.   A one month old, top end UPS supply should NOT require a Brain Dead procedure due to a failure.   For them to even suggest this is incredibly unintelligent.   It should be an immediate RMA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, I would RMA the unit ASAP.

Comment: Agreed. Why even risk it -- RMA.

Comment: I was having a little trouble getting an RMA out of them, so I thought I'd ask about while still pursuing the RMA. Finally got it out of them when it failed again. weee.

Comment: Shocking really.  The device is faulty, they should have offered an immediate RMA instead of trying to fudge into working a different way!  Good work!

Comment: I'm surprised. APC has always RMA'd stuff for me real quick, or sent replacement parts for things damaged in transit.